# How do I manage a single chef server to be used by all

Tags: chef-infra

I'm past being new to Chef, though NOT an expert by any means. Using open-source Chef, I'm setting up a **single chef server** that will have ALL my company's cookbooks that aim to install our product application on a VMs that's running a base OS, say RHEL 5.10. I'm segregating the cookbook files in version control, but how do I segregate them when I funnel them in the ONE chef server? Here are my challenges:

- My company has different products, say ProdA, ProdB, and ProdA and ProdB are totally different.
- Even though these two products may share common applications, the implementation of the application in each product is different. For example, even though I install ActiveMQ on both products, ActiveMQ is installed differently on each product.
- Also I need to be able to install, on a whim, different versions of ProdA software on VMs slated for ProdA. Same for ProdB, for VMs slated for ProdB. I will NEVER instal ProdA software on VMs slated for ProdB, and vise-versa.
- A certain set of cookbooks may work for v1.0 of ProdA software, while a different set may work for v2.0 of ProdA software
- One group of developers may be working on ProdA cookbooks concurrently; a different group of developers may work on ProdB cookbooks I want to segregate each developers' version of his/her cookbook.
- I want to segregate developers' cookbooks, from cookbooks used by QA, or the customer

Here's a simple work flow, extending my ActiveMQ I alluded to above

- Dev1 works on a cookbook to install ActiveMQ on ProdA. Also Dev11 works on a cookbook to install ActiveMQ on ProdB. Again even though they're both for ActiveMQ, the installation is different. How do we segregate the two ActiveMQ cookbooks, give them different name - ProdA_ActiveMQ vs. ProdB_ActiveMQ? **This just looks ogly!**
- Dev2 wants to tweak Dev1's ProdA/ActiveMQ cookbook, and does test it in his local environment. Now Dev2 wants other devs to try it so he uploads it to the chef server. How can we ensure that he doesn't break everybody's ActiveMQ installation?
- Version 1.0-1.4 of ProdA uses version 0.1.0 of ActiveMQ cookbook, but version 1.4-1.20 of ProdA needs version 0.2.0 of ActiveMQ. How can I model this?
- I'm working on a feature for Version 2.0 of ProdA. But my manager
  tells me to work on a hot field problem on version 1.44 or our
  product. How do I quickly know what set of cookbooks were used to
  install v 1.44 of ProdA?

I know this may be a loaded post. Is there a better forum for this? Can someone point me to a link where pieces of my scenario are done? Thanks.

Comment: Bascially you're describing the wrapper-cookbook pattern and the environment locking process, which is eased with berkshelf. [here](https://sethvargo.com/berkshelf-workflow/) and [here](http://www.getchef.com/blog/2013/12/03/doing-wrapper-cookbooks-right/) should be a good strating point.

Comment: I'll look at Berkshelf. I've seen the wrapper link, and will read more.

Comment: You'll have to define environment (development, staging, Qa, prod) and pin cookbook app A to version 2 in developing and 1.7 in Qa for exemple. Some googling will give you great answer which are not to be copy here

Comment: Yes I'm aware of the example where the 3 classic environments are defined - development, staging, and production. But it seems like I'll need "sub-environments" even for those. So Dev1's environment will be different from Dev2's, even though they're both in the Development environment. If only Chef had a concept of branches....

Comment: I don't see the point, just have two dev envs.  I've 12... If you feel the need, do it as you feel, you'll may end with some duplication but that should not be a problem

Comment: The classic problem with duplication is if I fix it in one, I'd have to fix it with the duplicates.

Comment: I was more thinking about 'link' duplication, same cookbook in 2 env in same version. So some attributes are duplicated in somes envs (smtp server etc.) But its not a lot of things usually

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When running chef at scale there are three ways to isolate configuration between users.

1. Use enterprise chef and setup an chef "organisation" for functional group of users
2. Use open source chef server and setup a server for each functional group of users.
3. Create chef "environments" for each functional group, within a single instance of chef server.

I would love to see more discussion or publications from users operating chef at scale. Some of us need to support dev teams who do not use chef and cannot live with a one size fits all server setup.

### Options 1 + 2

In practice, I have discovered that enterprise chef "organisations" are functionally the same as running separate servers. You still need to load cookbooks, roles, data bags, separately into each.

I maintain this approach is simple to understand but complex to maintain. Each instance of chef server/organisation requires its own chef repo, access keys and Jenkins loading jobs.

### Option 3

Using chef environments is harder to understand. Once it is properly understood I think it's simpler to implement. [Berkshelf](http://berkshelf.com/) is tool that makes it all possible.

First of all don't be mislead by the chef documentation. The examples of environments they give are global in nature:

- Development
- Test
- Production

This gives the impression that all production applications would share the same set of cookbooks. Once the number of apps starts to increase, you start getting into lots of trouble with conflicting run-times. Berkshelf v2.0 really sucked here... It frequently loaded inconsistent sets of cookbooks with absolutely no warning :-(

So.. Berkshelf v3.0 to the rescue and Jamie Winsor's blog posting on cookbook patterns:

- [Application, Wrapper, Library and Environment cookbooks](http://blog.vialstudios.com/the-environment-cookbook-pattern/)

The Environment cookbook pattern proposes a chef environment for each *application instance*.

- app1-dev
- app1-test
- app1-prod

The "Berkshelf.lock" is committed and saved into the Environment cookbook version and used to load the cookbook dependencies of a particular environment. An example of this pattern in action is the [berkshelf-api](https://github.com/berkshelf/berkshelf-api) installation.

The lightbulb for me was then I found the following chef search condition in the [haproxy cookbook](https://github.com/hw-cookbooks/haproxy/blob/master/recipes/app_lb.rb#L20)

```
pool_members = search("node", "role:#{node['haproxy']['app_server_role']} AND chef_environment:#{node.chef_environment}") || []
```

The members of the load balanced pool share a common role and environment. So... Either the role is application instance specific or the environment is!

Comment: Thanks, I will study this in depth, and especially the Berkshelf plugin which I've been reading a lot about lately. I'll look at the haproxy cookbook example. Since it may take an act-of-god to get Chef Enterprise, I'm leaning more toward solutions that address open-source Chef.

Comment: @ChrisF Berkshelf is a wonderful tool and essential for modern chef development. I advise install the chefdk package, berkshelf is included.

Comment: I've been reading a lot more on Berkshelf, but I get the impression that it is git-centric. We are a subversion shop (for now and for a while), so I assume this will be a problem for us?

Comment: @ChrisF Berkshelf is unrelated to git or subversion. Berkshelf is used to download cookbook dependencies from a central repository called the supermarket. In operation it is similar to how Maven manages jar dependencies in Java or the bundler tool manages ruby gems.

Comment: I stumbled accross the Berfsfile Magic article https://sethvargo.com/berksfile-magic/ and see how Berkshelf can work for me now. The thing that threw me off is I've also read other articles where mentioning a SCM repo path in the Berksfile is discouraged. The Maven and bundler similes also make sense.

Comment: It still escapes me how to "automatically" prevent two users from uploading two cookbooks with the SAME name and metadata.rb version (e.g., ActiveMQ 0.1.0) but different contents. I know I can take "manual" measures like freezing my version of the cookbook for example, but yet this is manual, and I'll forget to do it.

Comment: @ChrisF Berkshelf automatically freezes cookbooks loaded into chef server (a useful feature). You are really straying into new question territory here. A comment cannot do this justice. For example check out the knife spork plugin for workflow in assistance with collaborating cookbook worflows.

Comment: Thanks Mark. I'm aware of the spork plugin, and have used it. You're correct, I've milked this to death, but i think I'm still sticking to my original thread.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned up in the comments, this is generally solved through the use of library and wrapper cookbooks. You would have a shared `activemq` cookbook (possibly from the community site or written in-house) which provides a the core configuration steps for ActiveMQ. The nfor each environment you would have a cookbook/recipe like `prod_a::activemq` or which sets whatever specific attributes or other things you need for that environment and then either uses `include_recipe` or LWRPs from the `activemq` cookbook. You can find more information about this environment cookbook pattern [on Jamie's blog](http://blog.vialstudios.com/the-environment-cookbook-pattern/). You can also check out [poise-appenv](https://github.com/poise/poise-appenv) if you want an intermediate layer of environment-y config. You can use [knife-solve](https://github.com/coderanger/knife-solve) to always see which versions of each cookbook are active on a  given node.